Trouble deducing a dipole's scattering cross section (optics)
(I've already visited this post but it begins precisely with the formula I'm trying to derive). I'm trying to deduce the scattering cross section for an electron bound to a nucleus in the far field:
$$\sigma_s = \sigma_T\frac{\omega^4}{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}$$
where:

$\sigma_T$ is the Thomson cross section
$\omega$ is the frecuency of the plane monochromatic wave to which the atom is exposed
$\omega_0$ is the atom's resonant frequency
$\gamma$ is the electron's friction coefficient

But I'm quite positive the textbook I'm following makes a mistake in the derivation of this formula since, when assuming far field waves emitted by a dipole can be treated as plane monocrhomatic waves, it takes said field's instantaneous Poynting vector to be:
$$\vec{S}=\frac{c}{\mu_0}|\vec{B}|^2\vec{e}_k$$
when it should really be:
$$\vec{S}=\frac{c}{\mu_0}\left(Re(\vec{B})\right)^2\vec{e}_k$$
Taking into account we are working with plane monochromatic waves, the former would yield a constant, whilst the latter would give a function of time and space. Can you please help me derive this equation? Or perhaps redirect me to some source where it is demonstrated properly?

It's the same, because $\vec{B}$ there is meant to be the real magnetic induction vector.

Not in this case, since he then proceeds to take the modulus of the expression he has for B involvig dipole moments instead of taking just the real part

That supports my point?

@JánLalinský how so?

Taking modulus of a vector does not imply the vector has complex components. Taking real part would imply so.

@JánLalinský right, but what I mean is the magnetic field B is represented with a complex vector, and in order to calculate the wave's Poynting vector you should take its real part, not its modulus. The textbook I'm following does the latter, which I don't think is right, given the formula takes Re(B)^2, not |B|^2

The first formula with $|\vec{B}|^2$ is correct only if $\vec{B}$ is real. Thus either the authors meant $\vec{B}$ is real there, or they made a mistake.
